# X5 e53 spare key doesn't work

Tags: bmw, keyless-entry, x5

I recently purchased an older X5 with two keys.

One is VERY worn and looks like it was used every day. It works fine.
The other looks brand new, but does not work as a remote.

I understand the keys charge while driving, but I've had no luck using the key functions with the newer looking one.

Any advice?

Comment: If you purchased it from a dealer or garage - then go back and get them to sort it. If it was a private purchase then there is usually a set procedure to "code" each key to the car, but both have to be done at the same time on many makes...

Comment: @Rob T You mean you've had no luck in using the *remote* functions with the newer looking key? Does the newer looking key open the doors and start the car correctly using its metal key blade?